# Влияют ли на размер apk файла неиспользуемые спрайты в карте спрайтов?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

у меня в проекте есть карта спрайтов с множеством иконок, из которых я использую только одну, например. Я знаю что при сборке движок сам отсеивает неиспользуемые файлы, но будет ли он отсеивать неиспользуемые иконки из карты спрайтов, ведь по сути это один файл, разбитый на множество спрайтов.

Comment: Этот вопрос мне тоже интерес, тоже подожду ответа)

Comment: Ну соберите проект со всеми спрайтами - чек. Удалите не используемые спрайты, соберите проект - чек. Вычтите размер проекта A - размер проекта B = получите результат. Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: По поводу спрайтов и увеличения размера - https://answers.unity.com/questions/1406451/sprites-increase-android-apk-size.html
Руководство по уменьшению размера проекта - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html

Answer (score 0):

в зависимости от того как не использующиеся спрайты влияют на итоговый размер карты
если у вас карта 600x600, то неважно сколько на ней не используется спрайтов. вес будет одинаковый.